# Redirect a html file to the localhost on port 8080

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, localhost

I have a simple webpage that uses that okta web api:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <title>Simple Web Page</title>
        <style>
            h1 {
                margin: 2em 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- widget stuff here -->
        <script src="https://ok1static.oktacdn.com/assets/js/sdk/okta-signin-widget/2.16.0/js/okta-sign-in.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="https://ok1static.oktacdn.com/assets/js/sdk/okta-signin-widget/2.16.0/css/okta-sign-in.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://ok1static.oktacdn.com/assets/js/sdk/okta-signin-widget/2.16.0/css/okta-theme.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center">Test</h1>
            <div id="messageBox" class="jumbotron">
                You are not logged in. 
            </div>
            <!-- where the sign-in form will be displayed -->
            <div id="okta-login-container"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
                baseUrl: "{{ https://dev-8490637.okta.com }}",
                clientId: "{{ 0oa97ptccRHXCE3kN5d5 }}",
                authParams: {
                    issuer: "default",
                    responseType: ["token", "id_token"],
                    display: "page",
                },
            });

            if (oktaSignIn.token.hasTokensInUrl()) {
                oktaSignIn.token.parseTokensFromUrl(
                    // If we get here, the user just logged in.
                    function success(res) {
                        var accessToken = res[0];
                        var idToken = res[1];

                        oktaSignIn.tokenManager.add("accessToken", accessToken);
                        oktaSignIn.tokenManager.add("idToken", idToken);

                        window.location.hash = "";
                        document.getElementById("messageBox").innerHTML = "Hello, " + idToken.claims.email + "! You just logged in! :)";
                    },
                    function error(err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                oktaSignIn.session.get(function (res) {
                    // If we get here, the user is already signed in.
                    if (res.status === "ACTIVE") {
                        document.getElementById("messageBox").innerHTML = "Hello, " + res.login + "! You are *still* logged in! :)";
                        return;
                    }
                    oktaSignIn.renderEl(
                        { el: "#okta-login-container" },
                        function success(res) {},
                        function error(err) {
                            console.error(err);
                        }
                    );
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have python installed on my laptop.

When I open the terminal of visual studio code that contain my index.html file I use the commands:

```
cd C:\Users\marta\test (directory where my code is)
python -m http.server 8080 (redirect to port 8080)
```

I checked if my firewall/anti-virus was enable google to run and its correct.
The problem: When I load the http://localhost:8080/ is continuing show me this error:

[image: localhost refused to connect.]

Comment: You've a chrome error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, check this list to fix the error https://www.clickssl.net/blog/err_connection_refused-in-chrome

Comment: I tried all and still not working

Comment: what does the terminal say after the `python` command to start the server

Comment: Nothing! Doesn't give any error

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to verify if the port 8080 is open

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
```

If it is not Trying, then it is open. Ctrl+C to break this connection
If it says no telnet command, try to install telnet-client in Windows Component.

Answer (score 0):

you can first verify if the port on the desktop is open. If not open, usually HTML files don't need localhost. They can be opened from the file manager where the file is located. Still, you can check the localhost is open or not using:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
```

or

```
localhost:8080
```

can be entered into the browser and checked.